# how to connect database in j2me application for nokia s40 platform

Tags: java-me

I am developing a mobile app using j2me for Nokia s40 platform. I need to store data of application in Database. The database size is around 2 MB in sqlite.  So my question is which database is better to choose for my application please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi any idea please share

Answer (score 0):

Try [RMS](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=435). It is used to persistently store data on j2me devices.